# Why this import d3-scale statement triggers 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token import'

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a very simple code written in es6

```
import { scale } from 'd3-scale';

const a = scale.scalePow().domain([0, 20]).range([0, 1, 2, 30, 560, 1]);

console.log(a(1));
```

The dependency 'd3-scale' can be installed by

```
npm install d3-scale --save
```

I ran the following command to execute the script:

```
npx babel-node scale_words.js
```

And I got this error:

```
/Users/antkong/scale_series.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { scale } from 'd3-scale';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
    at loader (/Users/antkong/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/antkong/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/antkong/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:154:22)
```

I do not expect this error at all. The import statement looks normal to me.

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "d3-scale": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "jsdom": "^11.3.0",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

I am using

`node` v8.7.0

and

`npm` 5.5.1

I have tried rerun `npm install` but it does not fix the problem. In the same folder I have another script with these import statements

```
import 'jsdom-global/register';
import 'canvas';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
```

And it can be run with `npx babel-node` alright

If I use alternative syntax, it can run without any issue

```
var d3Scale = require("d3-scale")
var a = d3Scale.scalePow().domain([0, 20]).range([0, 1, 2, 30, 560, 1]);
;

console.log(a(1))
```

Comment: The error message suggests it was not compiled at all. Something is wrong with  your `babel-node`, not with the code.

Comment: I have even removed `node_module` and rerun `npm install` but it did not fix the problem. Besides I can run other es6 script with no problem

Comment: Other ES6 scripts with `import` statements?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the question with the `import` statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `only` entry in the `.babelrc` in the same folder. It excludes the `scale_words.js` from being executed as an es6 file.